# Create a list of tibbles with unique names using a for loop

Tags: r, data-structures, tibble

I'm working on a project where I want to create a list of tibbles containing data that I read in from Excel. The idea will be to call on the columns of these different tibbles to perform analyses on them. But I'm stuck on how to name tibbles in a for loop with a name that changes based on the for loop variable. I'm not certain I'm going about this the correct way. Here is the code I've got so far.

```
filenames <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "xlsx")
RawData <- list()
for(i in filenames) {
  RawData <- list(i <- tibble(read_xlsx(path = i, col_names = c('time', 'intesity'))))
}
```

I've also got the issue where, right now, the for loop overwrites `RawData` with each turn of the loop but I think that is something I can remedy if I can get the naming convention to work. If there is another method or data structure that would better suite this task, I'm open to suggestions.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Your code overwrites RawData in each iteration. You should use something like this to add the new tibble to the list `RawData <- c(RawData, read_xlsx(...))`.

A simpler way would be to use lapply instead of a for loop :

```r
RawData <-
  lapply(
    filenames,
    read_xlsx,
    col_names = c('time', 'intesity')
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `map` from package `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
filenames <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "xlsx")

mylist <-  map(filenames, ~ read_xlsx(.x, col_names = c('time', 'intesity')) %>% 
             set_names(filenames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer by @py_b, but add a column with the original file name to each element of the list.

```
filenames <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "xlsx")

Raw_Data <- lapply(filenames, function(x) {

  out_tibble <- read_xlsx(path = x,  col_names = c('time', 'intesity'))
  out_tibble$source_file <- basename(x) # add a column with the excel file name

  return(out_tibble)
})
```

If you want to merge the list of tibbles into one big one you can use `do.call('rbind', Raw_Data)`